# ActionBarsherlock tab navigation with viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to use Tab Navigation in Actionbar Sherlock, and in which tab I want to have a Viewpager.Is this possible? And if it is, where to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/), a project by the same author of ActionBarSherlock. There are code samples in that page.